# Jersey Client opens too many Connections

Tags: connection, client, jersey, jax-rs

i run in some problems with my jersey rest api and a client.

This is how im using the methods on a server side:

```
@POST
@Path("/seed")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addSeed(Seed seed) throws InterruptedException {

    if (!Validator.isValidSeed(seed)) {
        return Response.status(400).entity("{\"message\":\"Please verify your JSON!\", \"stat\":\"failed\"}")
                .build();
    }
        save(seed);
        return Response.status(200).build();
}
```

If i run a Jersey client in a while(true) loop, there are connections open and won't close. So im running into a problem i have a lot of connections open and my network crashes. So i can't use my server any more. After the connections are closed i can connect to the server.

This is a client:

```
    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client client = Client.create(config);
    WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI()).path("api/seed");
    while (true) {
            ClientResponse cr = service.header("Content-Type", "application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, seed);
            System.out.println(cr);
            cr.close();
```

My Questions are:

What can i do on the server side, to prevent clients open a new connection?

How can i specify a max number of connections?

And how should i implement the jersey client to reuse open connection?

Comment: i use tomcat 6, i can specifiy in the server.xml the amount of maxThreads. but i dont want to change the server.xml, is there a way to do it in the ressource or in the client?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to limit Jersey resources at the web-app level. If you upgrade to GlassFish EE, you can make your resources EJBs @Stateless @StatelessDeployment(maxInstances=16)

The pile up of connections could be because of Keep-Alive settings. In Tomcat 6 there are two you can tune your connector with:

1. maxKeepAliveRequests, which defaults to 100. It's the maximum number of HTTP requests which can be pipelined until the connection is closed by the server. Setting this attribute to 1 will disable HTTP/1.0 keep-alive, as well as HTTP/1.1 keep-alive and pipelining. Setting this to -1 will allow an unlimited amount of pipelined or keep-alive HTTP requests.
2. keepAliveTimeout, which defaults to connectionTimeout which defaults to 60k ms. It it the number of milliseconds this Connector will wait for another HTTP request before closing the connection.

Comment: Our company is using Tomcat 6 so i can't change the Server. And as i mentioned above i cant tweek the Tomcat configuration because there are some other applications running on the same server.